# What is the dua when approaching someone powerful?

Tags: dua

A while back, I encountered this dua that you’d read when approaching someone powerful and they will give you what you ask without you having to fear because Allah will convince them. This is just a rough summary, I don’t remember the whole idea of the dua but it revolves something like this.

Years later, I can’t find it anywhere.
I was hoping if anyone knew what I was talking about and could share the dua? And the English with Arabic transliteration? Jazakhallah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assalamu Alaikum Brother

First of all, I'd like to clear one thing, it's not necessary to read dua in Arabic in order to get Allah's help. Mashallah, Allah gave you tongue, blessed you with a language as a medium to communicate. so make use of that particular language, make use of that blessing. Make dua sincerely in your own language, He'll definitely help you. There's no need for you to have a dua for something in Arabic it's not necessary like I said.

You can make dua like this "Bismillah, Oh Allah I'm approaching a person powerful in my view, none has the power to harm me except if you gave permission, you have the ultimate power".

Inshallah, you'll succeed.

Jazakallahu Khair for reading
be good to your parents and remember them as well as my parents in your dua.

Comment: Wa’alaykum asalam thank you very much! May Allah reward you and al the good you do